# One property of a power series

Tags: polynomials, operator-theory, power-series, partial-derivative, generating-functions

Let $G(x,y)$ be a power series in two variables such that it can be  rewriting   in a such way
$$
G(x,y)=a_0+a_1 x P_1(y)+a_2 x^2 P_2(y)+\cdots+a_n x^n P_n(y)+\cdots
$$
where $P_k(y)$ is a polynomial in $y$ of degeree $k$ and all $a_k \neq 0.$
Let us call such series as  $x$-*balansed power series*.

Suppose $G(x,y)$ is given  as a closed expression not in expanded way, for example
$$
G_1(x,y)=\frac{e^{xy}}{1-y^2}  \text{   or } G_1(x,y)=\frac{e^{x}}{1-y}
$$
Then $G_1(x,y)$ has a balansed series since
$$
G_1(x,y)=\frac{e^{xy}}{1-y^2}=1+xy+ {x}^{2}\left( \frac 1 2 \,{y}^{2}+1 \right)+ {x}^{3} \left( \frac 1 6\,{y}^{3}+y \right) + \cdots+
$$
and  $G_2(x,y)$ has no balansed series since

$$
G_2(x,y)=\frac{e^{x}}{1-y}=1+y+ x\left( {y}^{4}+{y}^{3}+{y}^{2}+y+1 \right) +{y}^{2}+\cdots
$$

**Question**  What conditions the function $G(x,y)$ must satisfy   in order its series to be balanced?

One set of functions  with such properties is obvious: $G(x,y)=F(xy)$ i.e. $G(x,y)$ is a function of one variable $xy$.

Is there any good analytical description of such functions?

Comment: I think the first example function is not balansed either since it should contain infinitely many terms involving the y's without involving any x's. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: The variables are not equal, I replace in the definitiion  *balansed* by *$x$-balansed*.